# Passing a parameter to a permalink

Tags: permalinks, parameter

I'm trying to create permalinks for a page that currently has parameters passed to it. The site was set up by somebody else and I'm not familiar with Wordpress

I have various pages which have URLs of the form /events/single-event/?u_name=<event_name>/ e.g. /events/single-event/?u_name=Hippy

I would like to be able to access these various pages via /<something>/<event_name>/ where I'm not too fussy about what <something> is. <something> can have a slash in it if required.

I've had a go at setting this up via RewriteRule in .htaccess but haven't had any luck.

Can someone suggest how I can achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: You'll need to look at the link Bruno has provided, and consult that somebody because you'll later need to change `$_GET['u_name']` to `get_query_var` assuming you have the rewrite rules applied.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mess with .htaccess since WordPress has it's own rewrite engine builti in. You are looking for this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule